# How to set/unset environmental variables just before to run my program in Code Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks fortran project fork, svn 11210 sdk version 1.32.0

I was previously using an older Code::Blocks version, so the options I saved are now conflicting with this new version, but I do not know how to change them.
When I run my program from within Code::Blocks (I press the button "Build and run"), the following text appears tin the log window:

```
Checking for existence: /home/me/fortran_projects/project/bin/Debug/Prevision
Executing: gnome-terminal --hide-menubar  -t Prevision --maximize -x  /usr/local/apps/global/codeblocks_fortran/1.5/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.:/home/me/fortran_projects/cdi/installed/include:/usr/lib64 /home/me/fortran_projects/project/bin/Debug/Prevision /home/me/Documentos/calc_config.conf (in /home/me/project)
```

You can see the string

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.:/home/me/fortran_projects/cdi/installed/include:/usr/lib64

inserted just before the calling to the program. It seems that I inserted it when I used the previous version of Code::Blocks. I also used an older version of gfortran, whose libraries where palced in /usr/lib64. I now use a newer version of gfortran, whose libraries are placed in another directory. So, this piece of command line, is conflicting.

I have checkd the following options but the conflicting string is not there:

- **Settings->Environment->General settings->Terminal to launch console programs**
- **Settings->Environment->General settings->Environment variables**
- **Settings->Global variables**

I really do not know where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending path ("/usr/lib64") was in the project's "Build options ..." panel, in the settings common to Debug and Release, under "Search directories" and under "Linker".

I have deleted it and now everything goes ok.